# Mac Time Machine + Microsoft Azure Blob Storage

Tags: mac, time-machine, cloud-storage, azure

I wonder if I can use Azure Blob Storage to store Mac Time Machine files. Is it really possible to mount a blob storage as a drive for Mac Time Machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it's possible (possible as in it's doable, not possible as in "download, install and you are done). It's possible to write Mac OS X driver (for example using fuse) that mounts Blob Storage as local drive and then emulates HFS to Mac OS X. However, in practice that's really hard task.

So in short: no, it's not.

You may have better luck with installing netatalk (and AFP) with Time Capsule emulation, and then mount Blob Storage to Linux server. That way Mac OS X just thinks there is some storage, not actual HFS volume (and it'll create `sparsebundle` to emulate HFS).

Comment: is this still the case since 2011? or did MS find a way?

Answer (score 2):

Azure blob storage is less than ideal for this purpose; as others have implied you would need to store all of the file system metadata on your own.

These days, though, the "Azure Files" service **does seem** to be a workable option using an Azure "General purpose" storage account.

It's generally unsupported, but you should be able to use TimeMachine to back up to a SparseBundle disk image (formatted as HFS+) in the same was as with most other file shares using the SMB protocol.

See:

- [Apple Time Machine Backup to Microsoft Azure](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_TDi3Et9-cs) *(video; YouTube)*
- [Mount Azure file share over SMB with macOS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-mac) *(Microsoft)*
- [Creating a local drive mapped with an Azure File Share for your files in the cloud](https://demiliani.com/2020/07/29/creating-a-local-drive-mapped-with-an-azure-file-share-for-your-files-in-the-cloud/) (not Mac-specific, but may have some useful information)
- [Use an Azure file share with Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows) *(Microsoft)*

.

If you would like to backup to a SMB file share with macOS 10.13.3 or earlier *(either locally or in the 'cloud')* you'll want to read this:

- [Turn off packet signing for SMB 2 and SMB 3 connections](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205926) *(Apple)*

.

Finally, if your system is so old that it doesn't support SMB version 3 (MacOS X 10.9 Mavericks *or earlier*), Azure Files allows the use of SMB 2.1, but *only* by setting up a separate VPN.

- [Azure Files networking considerations](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-networking-overview) *(Microsoft)*